# How signed numbers are represented using 2's complement

Tags: binary

One way to represent the signed numbers is using the sign bit.

Another way is using the `2's Complement`? Am i correct?

If yes,
consider the number 8. Equalent binary is `0000 1000`

Then According to 2's Complement method.

1. We will invert the bit so, `0000 1000` becomes `1111 0111`
   2.Add one to it so `1111 0111` becomes `1111 1000.`

with `1111 1000.` how they are representing the sign bits?

Answer (score 0):

In 2's complement the Most Significant Bit represents a negative value. So for an 8 bit number the decimal equivalent of each bit is:

-128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1

Hence 11111000 sums to -8.

Answer (score 0):

The "sign bit" would be the leftmost one: 0 - positive, 1 - negative. Another way to look at it would be (assuming 8-bit numbers):

```
number 8 -> 1000
+8: fill from the leftmost 1 leftwards with sign bit 0 = positive -> 0000 1000
-8:  fill from the leftmost 1 leftwards with sign bit 1 = negative -> 1111 1000
```

So when you work in 2's complement you actually have a varying number of "sign bits", in that example you have 4.

**UPDATE**:

Got it wrong above, where it says "leftmost", it should read "rightmost"

Comment: Assume that we have just given an binary 1111 0001 . How will you classify between signed and magnitude numbers. i.e, how many msb are used for sign bit

Comment: @Vinoth Yeah I got it wrong in my answer above, 2's complement is: copy from right to left up to and including the first 1, then invert everything  to the left of that. Anyway, you can always consider the MSB as a sign bit when you are working in 2's complement.

Comment: @gpecge  " varying number of "sign bits", ",  Is varying number of sign bit will be fixed one. or it vary from number to number

Comment: @Vinoth if you just want to know if the number is positive or negative, you can just look at the most significant bit, in the same way as 1's complement

Comment: in 2's complement sign bit is not used. so at end of 2`s complement we  get 1111 1000. Is we want to use the msb here to find the sign. My confusion is all 8 bits will be used for finding the value only?

Comment: @Vinoth in 2's complement you need all N bits to find the magnitude, but just by looking at the MSB you know the sign: 0: positive, 1: negative

Comment: Fine @gpeche I got it